# How can I difference id (number) and email (string) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have API and some of them return to only email and some return only id. For example:

user1
`value: example@example.com`

user2
`value: 1212391361783212`

I need that if I have input and wanna give value if the value is `email`. If the value is `id`, the input value must be `null`

```
<input value={???}/>
```

Comment: For future questions, consider providing more context by including a more complete code sample of the component. It may have been downvoted for not having this information. It also may have been downvoted for using the `reactjs` tag and not having any React or JSX code.

Comment: @MichaelFlores Thank you for your recommendations. I thought that no need React code,  It looked easy, but I need an idea of how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample is incomplete but what you're trying to do should look something like this. Rather than assuming any non-numerical response is a valid email, which can break in the future as the API changes, be explicit about what you're looking for as below.

```js
// Assume you're comfortable using a relatively loose pattern to match an email i.e. no overly strict formatting rules
const mailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
// Assume response is in scope and contains the API response with the email or id deserialized from the body
const value = mailPattern.test(response) ? value : null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string is a valid number using [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). So

```
if(isNaN(value)) {
    // value is email
 } else {
    // value is id
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/^\d+$/` combined with [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
if (/^\d+$/.test(value)) {
  // It's number
}
```